# SPARQL Query problem -> wrong answer

Tags: sparql

I want to select a triple using SPARQL. To do it, i'm using following query:

```
SELECT count (*)
WHERE {?s ?p ?o}
FILTER (?s=http://kjkhlsa.net && ?p=http://lkasdjlkjas.com && ?o=Test)
```

As answer i get fully wrong triple :( subject ist not equal to "http://kjkhlsa.net", predicate is not equal to "http://lkasdjlkjas.com" and object ist also not equal to "Test". Can someone explain me, what I'm doing wrong :(

edit1:
I have put the query into php file:

```
    $inst_query = 'SELECT * { <http://kjkhlsa.net> <http://lkasdjlkjas.com> "Test"}';
    echo $inst_query;
```

The answer from the echo was "SELECT * { "Test"}". Then i tried it with WHERE:

```
    $inst_query = 'SELECT * WHERE { <http://kjkhlsa.net> <http://lkasdjlkjas.com> "Test"}';
    echo $inst_query;
```

Here was the answer "SELECT * WHERE { "Test"}"...so, i'm missing the URIs, but this seems for me as php issue and not sparql problem.

edit2:
I've put the query into SPARQL Query editor and i get the response "no result"....but I'm sure, that i have this triple.

Comment: Which query engine you are using? Note that standard SPARQL does not support aggregates such as COUNT(*). Also please edit the post so that the SPARQL comes out correctly, in this form the query shouldn't even parse.

Comment: sorry, i have no idea, which engine I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its current form the question is not very clear (see my comment above).

Since you are essentially trying to get triples matching a pattern, it is more efficient to use a graph pattern instead of `FILTER`. Many SPARQL implementations first match candidate triples by graph patterns and only then apply the `FILTER` expression. In essence, with a `?s ?p ?o` graph pattern, you're doing a linear scan over all your triples.

So, here's something that should work, using graph patterns instead of FILTER.

```
SELECT * { <http://kjkhlsa.net> <http://lkasdjlkjas.com> "Test" }
```

Notes: I didn't include `COUNT(*)` which is not standard SPARQL. `<>` around URIs. `""` around literal.

Comment: i have tried it, but still doesnt work. I'm ure, I'm doing something wrong... 
but that is not the query. Thanks for the hint with <> and "". As soon as I solve the problem, I will post the solution here.

Comment: You've added trailing slashes to the URIs Sirakov gave initially. So running the query you provided will not actually match what was intended since the URIs must match exactly.

Comment: @Phil M: Ah, a feature of the browser URL copy-paste function. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Sirakov: If it still doesn't work, please post additional details. Preferably by editing the original post.

Comment: It works, i need the "FROM"-Clause to specify which model must be used: SELECT * FROM MODEL_URI WHERE {<kjkhlsa.net> <lkasdjlkjas.com> "Test"}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :

```
SELECT count (*) as ?count
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o
FILTER (?s=<http://kjkhlsa.net> && ?p=<http://lkasdjlkjas.com> && ?o=Test)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query uses the count function to count the number of distinct URI(s) returned to the ?s variable.

```
 SELECT ?s (COUNT (DISTINCT ?s) as ?count)
    WHERE {?s ?p ?o}
    FILTER (?o="Test")
```